# struct pointer as parameter and return

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a function which takes a struct pointers as parameter and returns it.ın the function i want another function fill up the memory pointerd by the pointer.my code is

```
struct my_struct{
unsigned char** ps;
unsigned long*  pl;
};

struct* function(struct* param){

   another_func(param->ps,param->pl)//function takes pointers as parameters and fills them  up 
   return param;
 }

int main{
my_struct *p;
p=function(p);
}

//definiton of another func is;

void another_func(unsigned char**,unsigned long * ){...}
```

EDIT:it gives the error access violation

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: i suspect that "another_func" does something wrong, what does the {...} look like?

Comment: The thing is, why do you return the pointer to the struct? Either you pass a copy of the struct and return the editted copy, or you pass a pointer and return nothing.

Comment: Problem is that `p` is a uninitalized pointer which has a garbage address. You need to allocate memory for the structure. Simple pointer is not enough.

Comment: How are those values initialized? I mean, p, p->ps, p->pl?

Comment: struct* function(struct* param) looks wrong  - is it compilation errors you get?

Comment: no compile errors but gives error at runtime.another_function is a library function and it fills the parameters inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have posted so far try instead:

```
typedef struct my_struct 
{
  unsigned char** ps;
  unsigned long*  pl;
} my_struct;

void another_func(unsigned char**,unsigned long * ) {...}

my_struct* function(my_struct* param)
{
   another_func(param->ps,param->pl)
   return param;
}

int main()
{
  my_struct *p;
  my_struct q = {NULL,NULL};
  unsigned long pl = 10;
  q.ps = malloc( pl * sizeof(char*) );
  q.pl = &pl;
  p=function(&q);
  return 0;
}
```

edited after chat

Comment: it gives the error from the another_function() buffer passed is to small.it is because we assigned the static struct in main.for dynmaic allocation i can allocate a buffer

Comment: i didn't see that in my crystal ball, if you do not show all relevant info it is impossible to help. e.g. what is in another_func

Comment: there is nothing "static" in what i wrote, somewhere you need to allocate what `ps` and `pl` point to using malloc. e.g. `q.ps = malloc( 10 * sizeof(char*) );` ps and pl are pointers so they can only contain an address to somewhere. you need to allocate space so that ps and pl point to it. btw why do you not pass my_struct* to another_func instead of ps and pl?

Comment: ok understand.as syaing static i want to tell not with pointer.syntax coınfisuoın.

Comment: because another_function is not my function.is is from and external lib.it takes the parameters and fill them up so i pass the adress as parameters

Comment: ok understood. so another_func allocates what ps and pl will point to, judging from what you pass in it allocates an array of characters and an unsigned long.

Comment: yep.it is true.i found the basic implementation of it.should you wan to see

Comment: so what is not working? as i see it either another_func is supposed to allocate memory for you or you need to do that before calling another_func and it fills in data for you

Comment: it says output buffer is too small?.but it is the another_function job to fill the buffer

Comment: so this means that you need to create the buffer before calling another_func

Comment: maybe something like this       `my_struct q;
      unsigned long pl = 10;
      q.ps = malloc( pl * sizeof(char*) );
      q.pl = &pl;
      p=function(&q);`

Comment: ok i think so.and after taking the data.i need to free the struct all

Comment: yes you have free what you allocate, any malloc needs a corresponding free